# why non orthogonal states are indistinguishable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

I want to know what does it mean by distinguishable quantum state from Mathematics perspective I mean mathematically. As a non physics background student could any one explain me   why non orthogonal states are indistinguishable by using linear algebra only?

Comment: You probably meant that non-orthogonal states are not mutually exclusive - http://motls.blogspot.com/2014/07/non-orthogonal-quantum-states-are-not.html?m=1 - for two different but non-orthogonal states in quantum mechanics, there is always some probability given by the squared inner product (in absolute value) that one state will fully emulate the other, and some probability that it will not. You can't "prove" such things by pure linear algebra - it is a claim about physics so you need some postulates of physics (Born's rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two states $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ are perfectly distinguishable if there exists a POVM measurement $\{P_0,P_1\}$ such that

$$\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_0P_0)=1$$
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_0P_1)=0$$
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_1P_0)=1$$
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_1P_1)=0$$

and $P_0+P_1=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. You can interpret the above equations as follows: If we obtain outcome $P_0$, we know for sure that the state was $\rho_0$, whereas if we obtain outcome $P_1$, we know with certainty that the state was $\rho_1$.

It is not too hard to show that the above conditions can be satisfied if and only if the states are orthogonal. If they are non-orthogonal, there is always a non-zero probability of making a mistake when we try to identify which state we were measuring.